# Knockout js: how can i pass an argument to a knockout click function?

Tags: knockout.js

I have html button which has a n onclick function which takes the parameter of username this is my code and the  knockout-model class :

```
<span data-bind="if: friendRequestStatus() === 'ACCEPTED', click: removeFriend(user.userName())" class="call">remove<i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
```

this is the model class, with the removefriend function :

```
function usersProfileModel(data) {

var usersProfile = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);



usersProfile.user.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function() {

    return usersProfile.user.firstName() + " " + usersProfile.user.lastName();

});

usersProfile.user.playerStats.percentageWin = ko.pureComputed(function() {

    if(usersProfile.user.playerStats.matchPlayed()=== 0){

        return 0;

    }else {

        return (usersProfile.user.playerStats.wins() / usersProfile.user.playerStats.matchPlayed()) * 100;

    }

});


usersProfile.user.playerStats.percentageProfit =  ko.pureComputed(function() {

    if(usersProfile.user.playerStats.wallet() > 0.00){

        return (usersProfile.user.playerStats.profit() / usersProfile.user.playerStats.wallet()) * 100;

    }else {

        return 0;

    }

});

usersProfile.mutualFriendsPercentage =  ko.pureComputed(function() {

    if(usersProfile.mutualFriendsCount() > 0){

        return (usersProfile.mutualFriendsCount() / usersProfile.friendsCount()) * 100;

    }else {

        return 0;

    }

});

usersProfile.addFriend = function() {

    showNotification('top-right','info','Awaiting response', 250, 2000);

};

usersProfile.removeFriend = function(username) {


    alert(username);

    swal({

        toast:true,
        position: 'top-right',
        width: 250,
        title: 'Removing...',
        text: 'please hold on.',
        onOpen: () => {
            swal.showLoading()
        }
    }).then((result) => {

    });

    $.get("http://localhost:8080/friendrequest/send/" + username, function(data, status){

        self.usersOnScreen(data.content);
    });

};


return usersProfile;
```

}

This code works, but with one slight error, when the page loads, the function gets called without me even clicking the button. why is this and how can i stop it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the binding is applied (`ko.applyBindings`), the binding's value is evaluated. Since your binding value is an actual call to the method, it runs `removeFriend`.

If you want to *bind* an argument to the function without calling it, you can use `bind`:

```
click: removeFriend.bind($data, user.userName())
```

You can also create a method that returns a function in your viewmodel:

```
usersProfile.friendRemover = function(name) {
  return () => usersProfile.removeFriend(name());
}
```

with `click: friendRemover(user.userName)`.